# extend Compass breakpoint mixin to avoid duplicates

Tags: sass, placeholder, mixins, compass

I am using Compass mixin to create media queries for retina like in example:

```
header {
  height: $header-image-height;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  @include breakpoint($standard-resolution) {
    background:
            linear-gradient(
                            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
                            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
            ),
            url(../../img/dist/xxx.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  }
  @include breakpoint($retina-resolution) {

    background:
            linear-gradient(
                            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
                            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
            ),
            url(../../img/dist/xxx_2x.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 1176px auto;
  }
  color: $header-color;
  @extend %montserrat-bold;
}
```

It works well. But if I put the same mixin into another element, I will get duplicated output of @media at the end - one for each element:

```
@media screen and (max-resolution: 1.9999dppx), screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.9999), screen and (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.9999), screen and (max-resolution: 191.9904dpi) {
  header {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), url(../../img/dist/xxx.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  }
}
```

And the same output for another elements. Is there any way I could somehow make placeholder from this mixin, so all elements would be under the same single @media directive?

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution to avoid duplicate code on the output.
First of all there is a good tool to manage breakpoints called maps:

```
$breakpoints:  (
'retina': 
//here put all your breakpoints
)
```

Second instead of putting breakpoint inside each target element, it is better to put @include directive to the root and inside it put all your elements with new directive respond to like this (I have created separate file for this):

*_retina.scss:*

```
@include respond-to(retina) {
  element1 {}
  .element2 {}
}
```

End not duplicated code))) I hope it will help somebody. By the way I have discovered that Compass sucks((( I wont use it anymore.